# Throttling - difficulty in defining the description

Tags: spellcasting, wfrp-2e

WE have a problem with the spell form the lore of Shadow, named Throttling.
(warhammer 2ed).

Spell description:
You send ropes of inky darkness to throttle any one target within 12 yards (6 squares), cutting of his ability to breath entirely and forcing him to make a Thoughness Test to resist the effect the spell. You can maintain this spell with half action on each subsequent round, but you may cast no futher spells while doing so. If u maintain the spell, the Thoughness Test is modified a cumulative -10% penalty each round until it is failed, at which point the target begins to take damage. The first round of failure causes a Mamage 1 hit that ignores Armour, and each subsequent round the Damage of the hit increases by 1.
No additional Toughness Test are allowed to resist damage after the first has been failed; the damage simply continues to compund until you stop, or are forced to stop, concentrating on the spell. The rules for concentration (see WFRP, Spellcasting Limits, page 144) apply.

And you see.
**1. One of my friends is saying that:**
In first round, after the target make  successful Toughness Test, wizard has to cast the spell *(if want to maintain it)* again and *(if successful)* target *(again)* has to pass Toughness Test (-10) if successful, then again wizard has to cast a spell... and the cycle repeats until the test fails

**2. When the other is saying that:**
In first round, after the target make  successful Toughness Test, wizard can maintain the spell with half action, and in the next round target *(yet again)* has to pass Toughness Test (-10) if successful, then again wizard sacrifice half action to maintain the spell... and the cycle repeats until the test fails.

**Which one is correct?**
And if there was any mistakes, then sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The answer is number 2

The spells description reads as:

> You can maintain this spell
>   with a half action on each subsequent round, but you may
>   cast no further spells while doing so. **If you maintain the
>   spell**, the Toughness Test is modified a cumulative –10%
>   penalty each round until it is failed, at which point the
>   target begins to take damage. The first round of failure
>   causes a Damage 1 hit that ignores Armour, and each
>   subsequent round the Damage of the hit increases by 1.
>   No additional Toughness Tests are allowed to resist damage
>   after the first has been failed; the damage simply continues
>   to compound until you stop, or are forced to stop,
>   concentrating on the spell.

This implies, that once cast (a full action) maintaining the spell costs a half action in the next rounds. It also means that once cast, there is no need to cast it again if it is maintained. If you keep maintaining it the test becomes harder until the victim fails it. From that point it takes damage until the caster stops, stops concentrating or the target dies.